# securing a ruby on rails installation

Tags: security, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I successfully used this tutorial: http://techbot.me/2010/08/deployment-recipes-deploying-monitoring-and-securing-your-rails-application-to-a-clean-ubuntu-10-04-install-using-nginx-and-unicorn/ for our ruby on rails server.

but I wonder if this installation is safe. what troubles me is that the same user "deployer", who is a sudoer, is running the application.

doesn't this open the possibility that by some form of code injection an attacker gets full access to the system (opposite to a common apache installation where the apache process runs as say www-data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, having the `deployer` user in `sudoers` doesn't necessarily mean an attacker is automatically root; the attacker will still need to run `sudo` to escalate from the `deployer` account.

You will be safer by requiring a password for `deployer` to run `sudo`.  You will be even safer if you restrict the commands that `deployer` can run with `sudo` to what's actually required than "everything", e.g., if `deployer` has `sudo` privs only so that it can reload nginx, then you can remove it from the "staff" group, and then add in a line to `/etc/sudoers` like:

```
deployer ALL=(ALL) /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

Please see `sudo` documentation for more details.

As a side note, the document you're looking at looks more like a basic deployment guide, rather than a "securing your site" guide.  Take a look at, for example, this [RubyConf](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bUGy-E10Zo) talk for something more security specific.